# jquery ui resize block up and down, vertical only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to resize block with jquery ui to get only vertical direction. Ok, on some examples resized has been done, by moving on bottom of block, but i need to be done from top direction and bottom direction.

Comment: you really ought to try checking the api before asking http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 4):

You should read the JQuery UI Resizable documentation first: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Resizable but here is the answer: You're looking for this property: handles. This allows you to declare the sides of the element from it can be resized: {n, s, e ,w}.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8gTj/  // You'll see the basic behavior.

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
  handles: 'n, s'
});
```

From there, you can play with the "resize" method and the properties of tht resizing object to resize it block.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This isn't an exact fix. It look as though even if you restrict the resizing to vertical, at the end of dragging it still sets a static width on the element. This breaks things that are expecting that to be a % or some other relative  value.

Answer (score 2):

### http://jsfiddle.net/N6syV/

```
$(".selector").resizable({
  handles: "n, s",
  resize: function (event, ui) {
    ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width;
  }
});
```

Comment: And how to add this on multiple blocks?

Comment: since your selecting a class it will aply to all elements with the class selector :)  if you select multiple elements with the same id it will however only work for the first instance of your selected id